# Freshly installed Visual Studio, It is not recognizing some things so it doesn't autofill

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[An example of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGf1D.png)

I couldn't get it in the screenshot but it does have selections for autofill but not the correct one. I've looked at a few other resources to try to fix this on my own but I didn't see any, or they were there but were lost in the search. This was a script made off Unity. Sorry if this is obvious, I am stumped.

Comment: Try add `using UnityEngine;` at the begining of your c# file

Comment: Make sure your visual studio installation includes [Unity Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows).

Answer (score 0):

The Correct Answer was that Unity didn't recognize Visual Studio with being the correct editor. In the Unity Editor, going to Edit, then preferences, selecting Microsoft Visual Studio as the external script editor fixed the issue. I'm hoping others trying to fix this later on do not get stuck with the wrong answer like I was.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go to package manager and download Visual studio editor or go to visual studio installer and download SDK Unity otherwise used Visual Studio code

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem.

Most probably it's s because unity did not open visual studio correctly,
you can fix that by going to:
(On Windows) - Edit -> Preferences -> external tools -> {your version of visual studio}

(On Mac) - Unity -> Preferences -> external tools -> {your version of visual studio}

if this doesn't solve the problem you can try to install or update the package for visual Studio support:
Window -> package manager -> {search your version of visual studio}
and install the package